# Add data in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

In this way I create my `recyclerview` contents:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(new String[]{"one", "two", ..."});
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But now I want add more data, for example, how can I add a new string `new String[]{"nine", "ten", ..."}` inside this `recyclerview`?

I need to add more data in this way. I also tried to see other discussion on stackoverflow, but nothing.

Edit:

```
private List<list> list;

rv=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
list.add(new New("1", "a"));
list.add(new New("2", "b"));

RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(Array);
rv.setAdapter(adapter);

rv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
    {
    ....
     if ( visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount)
                    {
                   list.add(new New("9", "A"));
                   list.add(new New("10", "B"));
                   //method 1, but don't work:
                   RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(list);
                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   //method 2, this method work but don't add nothing, the rv is recrated with new list. the user is forced to go on top in this way.
                   RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(list);
                   rv.setAdapter(adapter);
                   //method 3, return "cannot resolve method notifyDataSetChanged()"
                   RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(list);
                   rv.notifyDataSetChanged();
                  }
```

Maybe the solution is similar at method 2, but why i see the error: "Cannot resolve..."?

Comment: `new MyAdapter(new String[]{"one", "two", ..., "nine", "ten", ...});`

Comment: It was just an example. I add the data with the http protocol.

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85) generic adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to change your dataset from a `String` array to a `Collection` like a `List`.

Initialize the dataset as follows,

```
List<String> dataset = new ArrayList<String>();
dataset.add("one");
dataset.add("two");
```

Initialize the adapter,

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(dataset);
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

To add more items,

```
dataset.add("nine");
dataset.add("ten");

// notify the adapter that the dataset has changed
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**EDIT**

Applying this to your edit,

```
if ( visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
    list.add(new New("9", "A"));
    list.add(new New("10", "B"));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I get the warning on notifyDataSetChanged(): It will always be more efficient to use more specific change events if you can. Rely on notifyDataSetChanged as a last resort.

Comment: i recommend change: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to adapter.notifyItemInserted(dataset.size()) it would consume less resources

Answer (score 0):

Take an ArrayList<>(), say stringList and add data to it. And then notify your adapter about dataset change.

Initialize your adapter with this data structure.

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(stringList);
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Add more items with this call.

```
private void addItem(String item) {
  stringList.add(item);
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Helpme if your list is small then you might consider a plain ListView
If you want to use the recyclerview I would suggest you consider putting your data in the SQLite database. Use a Model Class to work in conjunction with the DBHelper Class and the Adapter Class. Here are a few links
[List View](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter)

[Recycler View](https://github.com/teocci/AndroidGuidenotes/wiki/Using-the-RecyclerView)